# convert many JSON objects from one file to one XML file with as many elements as JSON has

Tags: java, json, xml

Let say I've got many JSON objects in the same file test.json
For this example I have 3 of them like below.

```
{
  "Message": {
  "Id" : "111111",
  "country": "ENG"
  }
}
{
  "Message": {
  "Id" : "222222",
  "country": "USA"
  }
}
{
  "Message": {
  "Id" : "333333",
  "country": "RPA"
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to convert those 3 JSON objects to one XML with 3 elemnts as a string.
 My code using org.jason is:

```
 String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("..\\myFolder\\Tests\\test.json")));
 String xml = XML.toString(new JSONObject(content));
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work expected way because it finds and convert to XML only the first JSON object from the file  test.json (Id:11111).

How can I convert 3 JSON objects from the same file at once to XML string???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your input is not a valid JSON as it is. It would be valid if the objects were enclosed in an array like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "Message":{  
         "Id":"111111",
         "country":"ENG"
      }
   },
   {  
      "Message":{  
         "Id":"222222",
         "country":"USA"
      }
   },
   {  
      "Message":{  
         "Id":"333333",
         "country":"RPA"
      }
   }
]
```

Then you would instantiate an array `JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(content)` and it would work.

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);
    JSONObject finalJSONObj = new JSONObject();
    finalJSONObj.put("MessageItem", jsonArray);
    String xml = XML.toString(finalJSONObj, "Messages");
    System.out.println(xml);
```

Will give you:

```
<Messages>
    <MessageItem>
        <Message>
            <country>ENG</country>
            <Id>111111</Id>
        </Message>
    </MessageItem>
    <MessageItem>
        <Message>
            <country>USA</country>
            <Id>222222</Id>
        </Message>
    </MessageItem>
    <MessageItem>
        <Message>
            <country>RPA</country>
            <Id>333333</Id>
        </Message>
    </MessageItem>
</Messages>
```

Comment: but then I get 3 XMLs but I need it as 3 elements in one XML file. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? I updated my answer with the final XML you'll get.

Comment: love it :) :) Thanks a lot